# How to hidden the message when loading in html page?

Tags: angular

I have one issue. Our logic is to show when the new user gonna add the new page for the first time there will be empty content so the message should displayed as `<p class="no-data">No Datasources to show. Please Create a new DataSource</p>`.

It works properly. But even though the user already used the particular page when he click one more time while loading period it shows the same message "No Datasources to show. Please Create a new DataSource". But it should not to be shown we should hidden the message for already created user.

```
        <div class="row" [hidden]="listView">
        <!--DATE:May-14-2018  -->
    <!-- start -->
        <div *ngIf="sources.length===0">
            <p class="no-data">No Datasources to show. Please Create a new DataSource</p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="sources.length!==0" class="col-lg-12">
        <!--DATE:May-14-2018  -->
    <!-- end -->
        <div class="row">
        <div  *ngFor="let source_info of sources;let i=index " class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="cat__core__step cat__core__step-- mb-4">
            <div  class="row">
            <div  class="col-md-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-3">
              <span  class="cat__core__step__digit">
                <img class="widget-logo"  src="assets/images/data_source_widget_icons/{{source_info.source.vendor}}.png">
              </span><!-- cat__core__step__digit -->
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9 col-xl-9 col-lg-9">
              <div class="cat__core__step__desc">
                  <span class="cat__core__step__title widget_name">{{source_info.source.name}}</span>
                  <div class="source-category">Category : {{source_info.source.category}}</div>
                    <div class="records">Version : {{source_info.source.version}} </div>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm icmn-bin" data-toggle="modal" 
                [attr.data-target]="'#delete_modal_widget_' + source_info.source.name" 
                     (click)="password=''" *ngIf="source_info.source.assigned ===  false"
                        ></button> 

                        <a [routerLink]="['../edit/'+source_info.source.name]" [queryParams]="{'display':source_info.source.category,'category':source_info.source.category,'vendor_name':source_info.source.vendor,'vendor_title':source_info.source.name}">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm icmn-pencil"></button>
                        </a>


                        <a [routerLink]="['../view/'+source_info.source.name]" [queryParams]="{'display':source_info.source.category,'category':source_info.source.category,'vendor_name':source_info.source.vendor,'vendor_title':source_info.source.name}">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm icmn-eye"></button>
                        </a>

              </div>

         <!-- cat__core__step__desc -->
              </div>

              <!-- col-md-9 col-xl-9 col-lg-9 -->
          </div><!-- row -->

          </div><!-- cat__core__step-- mb-4 -->     
      </div><!-- ngFor -->

      </div>

      </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this part:

```
 <div *ngIf="sources.length===0">
           ...
 </div>
```

the message is shown, when the `sources` array is 0.

You did not provide your control logic (.ts file), so I can only guess what causes that.

- maybe you re-initialize it every time the user clicks
- maybe you destroy the object on routing. Where do you store this `sources` object? In app.component, and the  is inside it? If not, it is possible that upon navigating, you destroy this object with it's containing page.

  - if this is the case, consider using [a shared service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

if none of the above helps, please provide more (control logic) code.